# How to deal with Lack of Multiple Inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, oop, multiple-inheritance

I am working on a mini-framework for "runnable" things. (They are experiments, tests, tasks, etc.)

```
// Something that "runs" (in some coordinated way) multiple "runnable" things.
interface IRunnableOf<T> where : IRunnable

// Provide base-class functionality for a "runner"
abstract class RunnerBase<T> : IRunnableOf<T>


class SequentialRunner<T> : RunnerBase<T>  // Same interface, different behavior.
class ConcurrentRunner<T> : RunnerBase<T>
// other types of runners.

class ConcurrentBlockRunner : SequentialRunner<Block>
class SequentialBlockRunner : ConcurrentRunner<Block>
```

Now, how can I reconcile `ConcurrentBlockRunner` and `SequentialBlockRunner`?  By this I mean:

1. Refer to them by a common ancestor, for use in a collection. (`IEnuerable<T>` where T = ??)
2. Provide additional base class functionality. (Add a property, for example).

---

I remedied #1 by adding another interface that just specified a type parameter to `IA<T>`:

```
interface IBlockRunner : IRunnableOf<Block> { }
```

And modified my `ConcurrentBlockRunner` and `SequentialBlockRunner` definitions to be:

```
class ConcurrentBlockRunner : SequentialRunner<Block>, IBlockRunner
class SequentialBlockRunner : ConcurrentRunner<Block>, IBlockRunner
```

Since `ConcurrentBlockRunner` and `SequentialBlockRunner` both use `Block` for their type parameter, this seems to be a correct solution.  However, I can't help but feel "weird" about it, because well, I just tacked that interface on.

---

For #2, I want to add a couple pieces of common data to `ConcurrentBlockRunner` and `SequentialBlockRunner`. There are several properties that apply to them, but not to their only common base class, which is all the way up at `RunnerBase<T>`.

This is the first time while using C# that I've felt multiple inheritance would help. If I could do:

```
abstract class BlockRunnerBase {
   int Prop1 { get; set; }
   int Prop2 { get; set; }

class ConcurrentBlockRunner : SequentialRunner<Block>, BlockRunnerBase
class SequentialBlockRunner : ConcurrentRunner<Block>, BlockRunnerBase
```

Then I could simply add these extra properties to BlockRunnerBase, and everything would just work. Is there a better way?

---

I know I will be recommended immediately to consider [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), which I began to work with:

```
class BlockRunner : IBlockRunner  {
   IBlockRunner _member;

   int Prop1 { get; set; }    // Wish I could put these in some base class
   int Prop2 { get; set; }       

   // Lots of proxy calls, and proxy events into _member
   void Method() { _member.Method(); }
   event SomeEvent
   {
      add { _member.SomeEvent += value; }
      remove { _member.SomeEvent -= value; }
   }
}
```

The problem I encountered (driving me to write this question) was that once you compose, you lose type compatibility. In my case, _member was firing an event, so the `sender` parameter was of type `SequentialBlockRunner`. However, the event handler was trying to cast it to type `BlockRunner`, which of course failed.  The solution there is not use `add`/`remove` to proxy the events, but actually *handle* them, and raise an event of my own. So much work just to add a couple properties...

Comment: If you need multiple inheritances - your design is bad. What is your actual case, without `A`, `B`, and other code names?

Comment: I can edit the post to provide the real names.

Comment: Add an explanation in text, if the names aren't enough to reveal the whole idea.

Comment: There are valid use cases for multiple inheritance in other languages...C++, for example.  But C++ doesn't have interfaces and extension methods.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan ..Totally agree with your comment about bad design.

Comment: @cHao I would love to hear about one.

Comment: @YoryeNathan edits complete. Hope it makes sense. I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible, but the events tend to complicate things.

Comment: You shouldn't separate the class into synced and asynced, you should provide synced and asynced functionalities within the class. Another logical way to solve this would be to make an interface IConcRunner or ISeqRunner, and make the base classes inherit BaseRunner and implement the IConcRunner/ISeqRunner interface.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Interfaces are basically multiple inheritance + abstract classes rolled up into one.  It's gimped MI, but the gimping removes a huge bit of the complexity.  In C++, you don't have interfaces, so you use MI (or, possibly, templates) instead.  But since each thing you inherit is an actual *class*, and not just a gimped lookalike, your "interfaces" can actually have *implementation* and each one can do the same thing the same way, rather than having a dozen classes implementing an interface (and each likely doing it slightly differently).

Comment: @YoryeNathan, What if I have other types of Runners that behave differently yet? The point of this "design" was to have base class runners <T> provide the behavior, and non-generic derived types, that provide "what" is being run, along with other ancillary data.

Comment: @cHao Still, logically, you should only INHERIT one thing, and IMPLEMENT as many as you want. Whether it is actually inheritance or implementation of classes or interfaces is just about terminology. Logically, you SHOULD, however, have that separation.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Then have a single runner class that gets a RunnerBehaviour enum value at the ctor and saves it as a readonly field, and behaves accordingly when it's methods are called.

Comment: Does this scream "factory" to anyone else?

Comment: @KyleTrauberman Not necessarily. It depends on the need. In any way, the issue the OP is facing will still be, even if implementing the factory design pattern.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand the problem then.  I'll re-read.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman sorry for the length, I did my best to keep it short, and well, failed.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Better too long than too short.

Comment: That's what she s...uggested, as I was writing this.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: It's not just terminology.  Interfaces can not have functionality; they can only *mandate* functionality.  As a half-assed example, consider `class NamedThingie : public Base, public virtual NamedItem<NamedThingie>`, where the `NamedItem` class encapsulates all the functionality of giving an item a publicly accessible "name".  Sure, each class could implement the functionality itself, but why?  If the functionality is entirely self-contained, it basically could just be mixed in to the class rather than saying "you must implement these functions, and *you must do it correctly*".

Comment: @cHao - your use of the phrase "mixed in" is interesting. Because most of the time, when people are raving about using Extension Methods to implement mixins, they are only providing a method, (which can only operate on public members anyway). Here, just like you said, one could plop something like a property in-place, which has no other interaction with the class. Which is just what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Yorye, blanket dismissal of a request for multiple inheritance as "bad design" simple shows that you don't understand.  The C++ designers added MI support for a reason, and I am confident that Bjarne is much smarter than you are.  Same thing is true in other languages.  MI is difficult to do right, but also highly useful.

Comment: Have you considered approaching this problem differently, and perhaps rather than coming at it from a traditional OOP point of view, consider something entirely different, such as AOP? So, you can inject 'BlockRunner' behaviour to some IRunnable<T> using aspects? When I hit an MI problem these days, I am starting to automatically think 'aspect' instead of 'object'.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am entitled to my own opinion. I am not disrespecting Bjarne and the C++ language, but there IS a big difference, how I see it, between how we viewed things in the late 70's and how we do today, in 2012. We have progressed and changed, just as C# that came later on changed from C++ in regards to the matter of MI.

Comment: @Yorye: There is a big difference between the programmers C# caters to and the ones C++ is designed for.  C# discards many features, not because they aren't useful, but because they're difficult to do right (sometimes for the programmer, more often for the compiler writers).  For example, C# offers nothing approaching the capability of C++ templates.  This isn't "we learned something in 20 years of experience", this is "programmers skilled enough to deal with templates and their error messages aren't looking for a new language, let's make a simpler language for the programmers who aren't."

Comment: @BenVoigt You say "simple", as if it is a bad thing. I suppose that different perspectives and views is what it's all about. I was just going for Single Inheritance because it is more logical to me.

Comment: @Yorye: "Simple" can be a good thing, maybe even is in most circumstances.  But when you start telling people "you don't need that" for no better reason than "it isn't simple", you run the risk that you're talking to someone who can make a complicated tool shine.

Comment: @BenVoigt Wouldn't you be able to do everything you want without MI? It only changes the design and structure. As I see it, it goes well with OOP, and when simple things are put together you get a complex mixture that can be a beautiful piece of work (still, being simpler than just a complicated one - simpler to maintain, to extend and to modify).

Comment: @Yorye: Most applications of MI I can substitute with C++ templates... but C# doesn't support inheritance from a generic argument either.  COM aggregation is another way to provide the benefits of MI without language support (although it tends to include more forwarding).  C#'s options in this respect are.... limited.  Composition lets you reuse from multiple "base classes", but as Jonathon pointed out, you still have an object identity problem.

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), FTW!

To be more explicit:

```
class SequentialRunner<T> : RunnerBase<T>
```

should implement `IRunnableOf<T>` and proxy the `RunnerBase<T>` without inheriting it.

```
class SequentialRunner<T> : IRunnableOf<T>
{
   private readonly RunnerBase<T> _runnerBase;

   ...
}
```

Comment: I agree, and am changing a lot around to make this work.  However, there are two big drawbacks: 1) Code duplication (for proxying of methods and events)  2) Loss of "base" type compatibility.

Comment: Extension methods and mix-ins sort of miss the mark, though.  The consumers of @JonathonReinhart's API should be encouraged to program against the most abstract thing they can.  Which means hiding the guts inside a nice shiny shell.  Not using Microsoft's syntactic sugar hack (as nice as they are) around the `sealed string` class problem.

Comment: @MarkSowul how do you extension-method your way into adding properties?

Comment: A property with complicated-enough logic that you would want to avoid duplicating it is almost certainly more suited to being a method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d(v=vs.71).aspx#cpconpropertyusageguidelinesanchor1

Comment: A property with complicated-enough logic probably isn't a property and needs to be promoted its own class.

Comment: For the record, Mix-ins are great things.  And can help ease syntactic acrobatics when using the API.

Comment: Composition and proxying ended up being the solution I went with. However, it was still quite a bit of work to simply add one *strongly typed* auto-property to each "derived" type.

Comment: I was rethinking this idea a bit after playing around with Massive and ServiceStack's OrmLite - I think we're missing some basic idea in OO somewhere that would allow this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension methods to create [mixin-like constructs](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2011/03/c-mixins-with-state.html), even with property-like elements.

I've also created an *experiment* with trait-like constructs in C#, [NRoles](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2011/05/nroles-experiment-with-roles-in-c.html).

But, all of these require non-standard coding, and will not be ideal for APIs that are meant to be exposed to third parties. I think you should try to rearrange your classes and use composition with delegation using interfaces if possible.